# Application class behavior on restarting application

Tags: android

I have a question regarding **Application** class of Android. I have a Boolean variable and I am changing this variable whenever I need to update via getter and setter method. But when I am killing my app **(by swiping from recent tasks list)** and restarts my application and accessing its Boolean variable it has always the **last saved value**. My question is when I am killing my application, does **Application class** not get killed or removed? Because default value of Boolean variable (I am storing) is true. If I am changing the value to false via setter method and killing the app and restarting my application again it still has false value in that Boolean variable. My assumption was it should have true value because the app has started again and all the variables should be reset (or should be given value whatever I am giving). Any help?

Below is the code I am using in Application class.

```
public class AppController extends Application {
    private boolean isAppRunningFirstTime = true;

    public boolean isAppRunningFirstTime() {
        return isAppRunningFirstTime;
    }

    public void setAppRunningFirstTime(boolean appRunningFirstTime) {
        isAppRunningFirstTime = appRunningFirstTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you "Force Stopped" the application? Killing the processed from recent app doesn't really need means that the application was indeed killed.

Comment: I don't get your point 'Force Stopped'. But what I am doing is lets suppose I press home button and my app goes on back stack and when I press button to get my apps back stack and I am killing my app from here

Comment: If I am killing my app or removing from recent app list doesn't it mean that I have killed my app or my process is killed?

Comment: You can go to "Settings -> Apps & Notifications -> "Select your app" -> Click at "Force Stop" button

Comment: When swiping an app from the recents, its process gets killed. So the boolean should be `true` at a "fresh" start. If it's not, you might have something in your code that changes its value. Show how you call `isAppRunningFirstTime` and `setAppRunningFirstTime`.

Answer (score 0):

The android application life cycle is quite complicated and depends on the types of components included in the application. If there are any services for example, the process (and by extension the AppController object) will remain in memory after you close a task from the recents screen. If you force stop it from Settings then the process will be killed and the AppController instance will be removed from memory. You might get a better idea of what is happening by adding some logs in AppController.onCreate() and its constructor or checking the result of android.os.Process.getStartUptimeMillis()